# Get list of running processes, get active process (and it's application) Flex/AIR

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

just a quickie (or maybe not:] ):

Is it possible to get somehow list of running applications/processes and, while running in background, check which process is active?

Additionally - if somehow, the answer was yes, is it possible to react for change of active window / application react just as if it was Event, or bind to it custom event (e.g. `Event.SystemActiveAppChange`)?

Thank you for answers as well as pointers.

**EDIT**: Due to probable missunderstanding, I mean *local* applications - on your win/mac/linux machine - I would like to (in process of learning of language) track what apps I use the most, make a little graph maybe?

So, the point is: in AIR app, developed in FLEX, I would like to get/list all running applications/processes, as well as which one is active (on user's PC/Mac/Linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible, since AIR can access neither process information nor system performance metrics.

Your only hope would be to create another service in .NET or Objective C (as in, not cross platform - assuming that is a requirement) that can provide the process information to your AIR app via a local `NetConnection`. I'm not sure about Java, but you might be able to get away with Mono.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If you're on Windows, you can try to get a .NET service up and running to provide the data to your AIR app. The .NET API you need is Process.GetProcesses() - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx. Not sure about OSX/Linux, sorry!

Comment: Well this seems like another idea cut down - I'm in no mood learn another language right now :D

Answer (score 2):

this is exactly the same thing I`m investigating!

While I think there are still no built in APIs to do this, with the new AIR 2.0 you can use [NativeProcess](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/interacting_with_native_process.html), so you can scrape the output of command line tools like **top** or **ps** on OSX. I actually have a proof of concept up and running which makes it possible for an AIR application to monitor its CPU usage inside the app using ActionScript, although it's a bit slow, couldn't go below 1.5 sec sample frequency.

But don't want to digress too much, I couldn't yet find out what command line tools could be used to get the active application / window, but I just opened a question to find out, which might be the workaround for your question: [Which command line tools can I use to get the currently active application / window on each platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845483/which-command-line-tools-can-i-use-to-get-the-currently-active-application-wind)

Comment: Great news then :) I will follow up:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use newconnection class to ping back and forth while applications are alive :
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/flash/net/NetConnection.html

1. the main app can send
   netConnection.send(mainConnection,"sendMessageBack")
   running on timer que
2. the child app will trigger in
   the sendMessageBack function
   netConnection.send(childConnection,"setStatusOk")
   .
3. the main app can check ( on same timer que as 1 ) if  setStatusOk was called if not shoot Event.SystemActiveAppChange

Comment: Hmmm, thank you, but there's is possible misunderstanding here :] Please, read edit.