# Get dimensions of a running instance of a program in AIR

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I would like to accomplish 2 tasks in AIR:

1. Determine, whether a defined program is running (for example firefox.exe)
2. If its running, then get the current dimensions of its window - i want to make a screenshot of the window, so i'd need other parameters too i guess: Is it minimized? is it behind some other window?

Is this possible to accomplish in AIR? Im using the latest version (2.6)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134481/get-list-of-running-processes-get-active-process-and-its-application-flex-air

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible out of the box. What you're going to need to do is write a native application in something like C# or C++ and then interface with that application using the NativeProcess API. Here is a video tutorial to something close to what you want to do, and should have you well under way.

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=125

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=126